# Oracle SQL strange behavior while using TRIM function

Tags: regex, oracle, line-breaks

Please find the two sql queries which i'm executing and their results.

> Code 1

```
Select TRIM(CHR(10) from Regexp_Replace('<html>
<body>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:8pt">Select CPU test and&nbsp; run for 1 loop&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></font></div>
</body>
</html>', '<[^>]+>','')) from dual;
```

> Result

```
>Select CPU test and&nbsp; run for 1 loop&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

> Code 2

```
Select TRIM(CHR(10) from REGEXP_REPLACE(DS_DESCN,'<[^>]+>','')) from Table1 where ID = 123;
```

where **DS_DESCN** is column with datatype as **CLOB** and in this scenario, **DS_DESCN** provides the exact same string as used in `Code 1`(string provided below).

```
<html>
<body>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:8pt">Select CPU test and&nbsp; run for 1 loop&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></font></div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Result

```
>
>
>Select CPU test and&nbsp; run for 1 loop&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
>
>
```

If you watch both the results, you can see in the `result` of `Code 2` is having line breaks at the starting and ending. Why this is happening and what changes should i make to `Code 2` to give result like `Code 1`

Comment: Probably the line breaks are stored as CR/LF, i.e. CHR(13) || CHR(10), in the CLOB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ThorstenKettner, the below code worked, but it doesn't look good.


`SELECT TRIM(CHR(10) from(TRIM(CHR(13) from(TRIM(CHR(10) from(TRIM(CHR(13) from REGEXP_REPLACE(DS_DESCN,'<[^>]+>',''))))))))  from Table1 where ID = 123;`

Comment: You can again use REGEXP_REPLACE for this. Two questions: 1) Would you be fine with removing all leading and trainling whitespace from the string, i.e. not only line breaks, but also blanks and tabs? 2) Can line breaks occur in the middle of the string and if so how would you want to handle that?

Comment: Yes, line break can occur in middle of the string and that _should not_ be removed off, landing and trailing once should be removed.

Comment: Here's a regexp_replace that works for me: `Regexp_Replace(str, '('||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||')*<[^>]+>('||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||')*','')`. (I was thinking that `\r` and `\n` should work instead of having to use the chr function, but for some reason it wouldn't work for me, hence why I ended up using the chr functions.

Comment: This is removing all the CHR(10) from the query, dose not work as expected.  as of now the solution which works here is 

`SELECT TRIM(CHR(10) from(TRIM(CHR(13) from(TRIM(CHR(10) from(TRIM(CHR(13) from REGEXP_REPLACE(DS_DESCN,'<[^>]+>','')))))))) from Table1`, It definitely looks **ugly** but it works. :)